# Is there a bijective function mapping Natural numbers to Natural numbers, other than $f(n) = n$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is there a function that can be bijective, with the set of natural numbers as domain and range, other than $f(n) = n$?

Comment: Yes, there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ such functions.

Comment: To give an explicit example, consider $f(0):=1$, $f(1):=0$ and $f(n)=n$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: An easy way to construct such functions: permute the first $n$ natural numbers and then let $f(m)=m$ for $m \ge n+1$.

Comment: @crvo84: related on MO http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27785/

Comment: [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) (a.k.a. binary reflected code) is another (non-trivial) such function.  For those who don't know, _Gray code_ orders the natural numbers such that each successive number differs from the previous in only one bit (binary digit).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are uncountably many of such maps.

In fact, let $A$ be any subset of $\Bbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ such that both $A$ and $\Bbb N\setminus A$ are infinite (for example, $A$ could be the set of primes or the set of perfect squares).
Then we can define $a(n):=$ $n$th smallest element of $A$, $b(n):=$ $n$th smallest element of $\Bbb N\setminus A$, and 
$$ f(n)=\begin{cases}a(\tfrac n2)&\text{if $n$ is even}\\b(\tfrac{n+1}2)&\text{if $n$ odd}\end{cases}$$
Different $A$ will give different $f$, hence there are at leadt as many $f$ as there are $A$ - and that's continuum-many.

Answer (score 8):

Sure. Consider the function $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ defined by

$$
f(n) = \cases{
n - 1 & if $n$ is even \\
n + 1 & if $n$ is odd.}
$$

This function is a non-identity bijection. As *Hagen von Eitzen* notes, depending on your definition of $\Bbb N$, swap $+$ and $-$ in the definition of $f$ if $\Bbb N = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$.

Comment: Note that $f(0)=-1$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat This method works if $\Bbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. For $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ swap $+$ and $-$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, depending on your definition of the naturals, this is a valid bijection. In particular, $\Bbb N$ does not *have* to contain $0$, and this is largely a matter of convention, anyway.

Comment: @AOrtiz You should mention that. What you consider N to be. Or better, as Hagen says, add the alternative.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, done. Thanks for the advice. It is always best to be explicit with these things.

Comment: @AOrtiz You're welcome.